# Using the Month function as criteria in an Access SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to extract data from an Access 2016 database using SQL and VBA.  Below is the code I'm trying to use and every time I run it, I get a "No value given for one or more parameters". I've also shown what I see in the immediate window.

```
vsql = "SELECT [ResDate],[ResNanme],[ResStart],[ResEnd] FROM [TrainingRoom] where Month([ResDate]) = " & MonNo

Set RecSet1 = Connection.Execute(vsql, dbrows, adCmdText)
```

Immediate Window:

```
SELECT [ResDate],[ResNanme],[ResStart],[ResEnd] FROM [TrainingRoom] where(Month([ResDate])) = 11
```

I don't see anything wrong but I'm sure this is user error.  The "MonNo" variable is declared as an integer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.....

Comment: Please show full code especially the `Connection` object. We need to see what API you are using. Also, does that immediate window query work in MS Access if you run in SQL query window? Are you prompted to enter a parameter and if so which one?

Comment: Your immediate window string doesn't match the VBA provided (it has more parentheses, misses a space). Please share your actual code

Comment: That error typically indicates a missing or misspelled field or table name.

Comment: @Gustav.....You are correct about the misspelled field name.  The field name should be "ResName" and not "ResNanme".  Once I corrected that spelling, it worked as I expected it to.  User error = me.....I looked at that until my eyes were blurry.....Thanks again for your help...…..

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Execute method to open ADO recordset, only Open.

Assuming Connection is a declared and set variable - but it is a reserved word and really should not use as a variable. If code is behind same db pulling data from, could just use CurrentDb with DAO recordset variable and OpenRecordset method. Example that accepts default parameters for optional arguments:

```
Dim RecSet1 As DAO.Recordset
Set RecSet1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(vsql)
```

Comment: Assuming `Connection` represents an ADODB connection (which is likely due to the arguments being used), `.Execute` can be used to open a recordset. However, the question is lacking a [mre]

Comment: Okay, revised answer.